# Transition-group stagger not working (Vue 2)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

I'm trying to get the vue transition-group stagger to work per the example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Staggering-List-Transitions

Specifically I am not seeing the transition happen on load. In my codepen (below) the add button works and fade happens for new items added to the list but again not on load.

https://codepen.io/robomatic/pen/RgLzJP

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      adding: false,
      page: {
        mediaGallery: [{
            sys: {id: "3Dke2aizfqEo4eWOyoe2Uk"},
            fields: {file: {url: "//via.placeholder.com/800x600g"}}
          },{
            sys: {id: "3Dke2aizfqEo4eWOyoe2Uk"},
            fields: {file: {url: "//via.placeholder.com/800x600g"}}
          },{
            sys: {id: "3Dke2aizfqEo4eWOyoe2Uk"},
            fields: {file: {url: "//via.placeholder.com/800x600g"}}
          },{
            sys: {id: "3Dke2aizfqEo4eWOyoe2Uk"},
            fields: {file: {url: "//via.placeholder.com/800x600g"}}
          },{
            sys: {id: "3Dke2aizfqEo4eWOyoe2Uk"},
            fields: {file: {url: "//via.placeholder.com/800x600g"}}
          },{
            sys: {id: "3Dke2aizfqEo4eWOyoe2Uk"},
            fields: {file: {url: "//via.placeholder.com/800x600g"}}
          }]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    delayedBy: function(el) {
      if (this.adding)
        return 0
      return 350
    },
    beforeEnter: function(el) {
      console.log("beforeEnter");
      el.style.opacity = 0;
    },
    enter: function(el, done) {
      console.log("enter");
      let delay = el.dataset.index * this.delayedBy();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300, done);
      }, delay);
    },
    leave: function(el, done) {
      console.log("leave");
      let delay = el.dataset.index * this.delayedBy();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300, done);
      }, delay);
    },
    addItem() {
      let item = {
        sys: {id: Math.random().toString().substring(2)},
        fields: {file: {url: "//via.placeholder.com/800x600"}}
      }
      this.adding = true;
      this.page.mediaGallery.push(item)
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `appear` attribute to your `<transition-group>` for [transitions on initial render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render)

```
<transition-group appear></transition-group>
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/rvams1993/pen/GEOvpN) of your working transition on load